# how to make the system ask root before copying each file in Linux centos 6.5

Tags: linux, centos6.5

I have code to copy files from find output but I need to ask before copy each files

```
find  -type f  -atime +6  -size -6000k -user root -exec cp -i {} /root/myfiles \;
```

please can you help me with that

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not within the bounds of discussion as described in the help center.

Comment: the `-i` flag should prompt (interactive) for each file. If it's not doing this, then you need to update your Q and specify exactly what is happening, (are all file files copying, are none of them copying, do you get any error messages?) AND this is really more appropriate to https://unix.stackexchange.com or https://superuser.com . Please read the [help] and [mcve] before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: I need before each any file ask me even it doesn't exist before

Comment: In that case you'll need to write a wrapper script that you invoke instead of the `cp` command.  And you may want to update the question with that information...